# ConnectionManager details revert back

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a ConnectionManager called: Database1.  I want to change the connection string for Database1.  Therefore I follow these steps:

1. Double click on the connection manager for Database1
2. Change the server, database, username and password.
3. These the connection

However, when I build the project the settings revert back to the old connection.  Why is this?

Comment: is the connection string bound to an expression evaluation or a package configuration?

Comment: @SFrejofsky, it is a dynamic connection.  Therefore an expression evaluation.

Comment: That would be why its not changing... you would need to change the contributing factors to the dynamic connection for it to change. it is going to evaluate based on the dynamic elements of the connection string property. What is the expression that drives the connection string.

Comment: @SFrejofsky, a connection manager is set at design time. Why would it change during a build? The connection strings are held in a database table.

Comment: Building the project evaluates the expressions and package configurations.  A connection manager might be configured during design, but it should be configurable so that the package can run in different environments.  So the short answer is change the settings in the database to what you want the connection manager to use.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz Well said